# setting a different default value for a column

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I generate a different default value for a column in SQLAlchemy model? In the following example, I am getting the same default value for every new instance of the model object.

```
import random, string

def randomword():
    length = 10
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in range(length))

class ModelFoo(AppBase):
    temp = Column("temp", String, default=randomword())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`default=randomword()` is wrong. Since the function has called so become a constant, it is not a function any more. Pass a callable function if you want to get different values every execution:

```
import random, string
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sess = Session()

def randomword():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in xrange(10))

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    key = Column(String, primary_key=True, default=randomword)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Demo:

```
>>> sess.add(Foo())
>>> sess.add(Foo())
>>> sess.add(Foo())
>>> sess.flush()
>>> [foo.key for foo in sess.query(Foo)]
[u'aerpkwsaqx', u'cxnjlgrshh', u'dszcgrbfxn']
```

Comment: Strange. Any suggestions how to debug what's going on in my case? Thanks.

Comment: @gablubablu How did you figure out that inserted values are totally same? Queried via ORM session or checked dbms manually?

Comment: @gablubablu Try print raw SQL. There is an `echo=True` option for `create_engine()` to simply configure putting debug logs.

Comment: I tried your sample. If you change default=randomword to default=randomword(), you will see the problem too.  Any idea why?

Comment: @gablubablu Ah that was the problem. Since the function has called and evaluated, it is not a function any more. Since `default=randomword()` evaluated, SQLAlchemy understands it as `default='somerandomword'`. For the future reference, I suggest you edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

default=randomword will solve the issue.

Not useful for you case, but there is another default called 'server_default' which sits at the DB. So, even if you are manually inserting rows, 'server_default' gets applied.